# why doesn't my motorcycle power on?

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, suzuki, sv650

I have a Suzuki sv 650 2007. My bike recently turned on head lamps, tail, and gauges. Now it won't power on at all, not even a jump start can turn the power on. What can I do to solve the cause?

Does this mean I'm in the frying pan?

I tried to jump start it with cables and a car. Did I blow up the fuses?

Is there something I should be concerned about?

I also heard a whiney noise from the bottom somewhere from the bike.

What does that mean?

Comment: Simple things first, is the cut off switch set to run or cut off? normally on the right handlebar and marked on/off. SEcondly do you get any power at all, do gauges light up? brake lights? what voltage is on the battery?

Comment: At first the power would come on like the head lamps ,tail s, and gauges. But ever since I jumped started it won't power on at all.

Comment: How do I put it on neutral?

Comment: Neutral is a half click between 1st and 2nd. Check the engine shutoff switch and kickstand switch. Check the voltage with a voltmeter across the battery terminals.

Comment: Also, check for blown fuses. I believe the SV650 uses the blade fuses. You can just pop them out and easily look at them to see if they are burnt. You may also want to check the clutch safety switch, and make sure it's not bent.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you connected the positive terminals and negative terminals together on the jump, there shouldn't have been any harm done to the bike's electrical system or battery.

Take the battery to an auto parts store and have them test it. If the battery fails their test, replace the battery.

Next, check the main fuse, usually on the same cable as the positive battery connector. If the fuse is elsewhere, look for a 30A (or similarly sized) fuse in the electrical stuffs - usually under the seat or the general vicinity of the battery. If the main fuse is blown, replace it with the proper amp and voltage rated fuse - consult the manual as someone may have previously installed an incorrect fuse. If it blows again, troubleshoot the cause of the blown fuse (one spurious blown fuse is not a reason to troubleshoot).

Then check the fuses in fuse box, doing as with the main fuse if any are blown.

Lastly, verify the function of the main relay. I'm not sure where it is, so you may have to go digging in the bike's electrical schematics to figure out which one is the main relay and where that relay is located. You can test it by just figuring out which lead is the lead to close the relay (not the one that powers the loads when the relay is closed), and connect the battery's positive terminal to it. Just be sure to secure your test lead to the relay before attaching the other end to the battery - you don't want to short it to ground. If the relay fails the test, replace it. If the relay passes, check the continuity of the ignition switch.

Comment: I noticed every place some fuses and they were blown out also I realize that when I jump start it the bike I had the negative on the positive side and the positive in the negative stupid me I need glasses but anyways I hope I did not blow out a solenoid and for the record I got a new battery and steel the motorcycle does not start no power absolutely nothing

Comment: this may sound like a stupid question only because this is my first bike how do I know if its on neutral I know it's a big red switch on the right hand side is that the kill switch if so that is not activating.I've notice like I said before I love the fuses are blown now I guess my next step would be to check the relays I have heard that sounds like a common theme the worst thing to do it sounds like is to jumpstart a bite with the car I really hope its the relay.

Comment: I really appreciate your guyses help I really do think you I'm going to give that a try and if anything I'll leave a comment with the status of my bike thank you

Comment: okay now my bike powers on but it does not start I'm thinking because its been sitting outside for a few months any recommendations

Comment: Does it turn over?

Comment: it does not start however when I press the start button it makes a little noise it's kind of hard to describe in words but  simply put its like a buzzy noise

Comment: It sounds like we have resolved the issues in this question. If my answer lead you to the resolution, please mark it as the answer for this question. For your starting issue, please start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If it turns over but doesn't start change the spark plugs if it's been sitting for a couple months

Comment: Great suggestion!!!

Answer (score 0):

Mine just did the same thing - mine was a fuse.  There are only two, both 20  amp, but one seems to control almost everything.  The fuses are under the seat on the right side, brake side, in a small white box attached to the frame.

Comment: Steve, are you talking about the component thats the starter relay?